# storing twiki post data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, twiki

TWiki is good wiki project. I have implemented it and using.
Bydefault Twiki stores data in files with extension .txt, is any plugin/method to store post data in mysql database?

How can I store data in mysql database for TWiki?

Answer (score 0):

sadly, no.

I built a MongoDB backend for foswiki (a TWiki fork) http://foswiki.org/Development/MongoDBPlugin with remarkable results, and Crawford and I began work on a Database backend for it, but the work is not complete yet.

I guess the big questions are - do you need it, and do you need it enough to help make it happen :)

SVen